# applying cumsum() from different starting points

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have data

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(42)
t <- data.table(time=1:1000, value=runif(100,0,1))
p <- data.table(id=1:10, cut=sample(1:100,5))
vals <- 1:5

> head(t)
   time     value
1:    1 0.9148060
2:    2 0.9370754
3:    3 0.2861395
4:    4 0.8304476
5:    5 0.6417455
6:    6 0.5190959

> head(p)
    id cut
 1:  1  63
 2:  2  22
 3:  3  99
 4:  4  38
 5:  5  91
 6:  6  63

> vals
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

where `t` gives some vector of `values` associated with time points, and `p` gives for each person a cutoff in `time`.

I would like to get for each person the time units it takes to accumulate each of the values in `vals`.

My approach now is to use a for-loop that computes for each person a temporary vector of cumulative sums, starting at its specific cutoff in `time`. Next, I use `findInterval()` to obtain the positions at which cumsum reaches each of the levels in `vals`.

```
out <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(p), ncol=length(vals)); colnames(out) <- vals
for(i in 1:nrow(p)){
   temp <- cumsum(t$value[t$time > p$cut[i]]); temp <- temp[!is.na(temp)]
   out[i,] <- findInterval(vals,temp)
}
```

which should yield

```
      1 2 3 4  5
 [1,] 1 4 5 9 12
 [2,] 1 2 5 6  7
 [3,] 1 2 4 5  7
 [4,] 1 3 5 7  8
 [5,] 2 3 5 7  8
 [6,] 1 4 5 9 12
 [7,] 1 2 5 6  7
 [8,] 1 2 4 5  7
 [9,] 1 3 5 7  8
[10,] 2 3 5 7  8
```

This is of course heavily inefficient and doesn't do justice to the powers of R. Is there a way of speeding this up?

Comment: Could you look again at your example data? For example, the condition `t$value > p$cut[i]` is always `FALSE`; consequently there is nothing to sum.

Comment: Let me check, pardon!

Comment: Apologies, I had confused two variables and chose `vals`unwisely to print it here. Should be fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do

```
# precompute cumsum on full table
t[, cs := cumsum(value)]

# compute one time per unique cut value, not per id
cuts = unique(p[, .(t_cut = cut)])

# look up value at cut time
cuts[t, on=.(t_cut = time), v_cut := i.cs]

# look up time at every cut value combo
cutres = cuts[, .(pt = vals + v_cut), by=t_cut][, .(
  t_cut, 
  v = vals,
  t_plus = t[.SD, on=.(cs = pt), roll=TRUE, x.time] - t_cut
)]
```

which gives

```
    t_cut v t_plus
 1:    63 1      1
 2:    63 2      4
 3:    63 3      5
 4:    63 4      9
 5:    63 5     12
 6:    22 1      1
 7:    22 2      2
 8:    22 3      5
 9:    22 4      6
10:    22 5      7
11:    99 1      1
12:    99 2      2
13:    99 3      4
14:    99 4      5
15:    99 5      7
16:    38 1      1
17:    38 2      3
18:    38 3      5
19:    38 4      7
20:    38 5      8
21:    91 1      2
22:    91 2      3
23:    91 3      5
24:    91 4      7
25:    91 5      8
    t_cut v t_plus
```

If you want to map this back to `id` and get it in a id x vals table...

```
cutres[p, on=.(t_cut = cut), allow.cartesian=TRUE, 
  dcast(.SD, id ~ v, value.var = "t_plus")]

    id 1 2 3 4  5
 1:  1 1 4 5 9 12
 2:  2 1 2 5 6  7
 3:  3 1 2 4 5  7
 4:  4 1 3 5 7  8
 5:  5 2 3 5 7  8
 6:  6 1 4 5 9 12
 7:  7 1 2 5 6  7
 8:  8 1 2 4 5  7
 9:  9 1 3 5 7  8
10: 10 2 3 5 7  8
```

(Alternately, the key part can be done like `t_plus = t[.SD, on=.(cs = pt), roll=TRUE, which=TRUE] - t_cut` since `t$time` is the row number.)

Comment: Thanks, works great! However, in some cases, the `cutres = ...` step produces data.tables that have an extra line at the end which repeats `t_cut`of the first line and has `t_plus` equal some crazy high number. In your example, this would be `26:    63 5   1000`. I suspect this is due to the `roll=TRUE` but haven't figured out yet what causes this behavior. Any idea?

Comment: @bumblebee Re the value of `t_plus` you could try the other way of computing it at the end of the question or `t_plus = findInterval(pt, t$cs) - t_cut` both of seem which to achieve the same result. Or you could add `mult="first"` to the `t_plus = t[...]`, which will be needed if you have repeated values of `t$cs` resulting from `t$value` being zero, I think. For the extra row, I'm stumped, but you could have a look at intermediate tables like `cuts[, .(pt = vals + v_cut), by=t_cut]` to investigate.